# Simple Moving Average cross over strategy not working

Tags: mql4

I am creating a simple EA to place a trade on an SMA crossover. However, I cannot get the correct signal back from the checkEntry function. It is fine in most cases, but when the two lines almost cross then diverge again, I end up with the wrong signal. Can anyone spot what the mistake is? Also, I wouldlike to introduce a small buffer of say 1 pip after the crossover before the signal is given.

```
    string checkEntry()
       {
       double myFastMa = iMA(ChartSymbol(),Period(),varSma1,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,0);
       double mySlowMa = iMA(ChartSymbol(),Period(),varSma2,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,0);
       double myFastMaPrev = iMA(ChartSymbol(),Period(),varSma1,1,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,1);
       double mySlowMaPrev = iMA(ChartSymbol(),Period(),varSma2,1,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,1);
       double myTrendMa = iMA(ChartSymbol(),Period(),varSma3,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,0);
   
       if (myFastMa > mySlowMa && myFastMaPrev <= mySlowMaPrev)  signal = "BUY";
      
       if (myFastMa < mySlowMa && myFastMaPrev >= mySlowMaPrev)  signal = "SELL";
   
       //   Alert ("myFastMa is ", myFastMa," and myFastMaPrev is ", myFastMaPrev);
       //   Alert ("mySlowMa is ", mySlowMa," and mySlowMaPrev is ", mySlowMaPrev);
       //   Alert ("This gives a ",signal," signal");
   
       return signal;
       } // End CheckEntry()
```

Comment: There is an additional problem in that occassionally a second order is placed based on the same cross over event. So after a crossover occurs, on close of the next candle an order is placed and another order is placed on close of the next candle with no other cross over event happening.

Comment: It's OK. I've figured it out. Thanks anyway.